# Doubt on which part should need arrangement and which part shouldn't in a Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of permutation of the string $MADEEASY$ in which all vowel are together are?

Here I think that $5!$ is the answer, but answer given $\frac{5!4!}{2!2!}$
Is changing of vowel position make a separate word?
I mean when vowel are together, there is a word, but vowel together considered as a single letter, then why it's permutation makes a separate word?

Comment: As I understood the question "AAEEMDSY" and "AEAEMDSY" are different words. Your approach treats them as identical.

Comment: What you mean by assume? You are assuming answers?

Comment: @lesnik that means though the letters we combined as single word, but they are not at all a single word. And we have to take their arrangement too. right?

Comment: @ShamimAkhtar It is not correct to consider all the vowel's together as a single letter. If you do it the words "AAEEMDSY" and "AEAEMDSY" would become the same: "$X$MDSY$, where $X$ stands for the combined vowels. But these words are different. So the answer 5! is not correct.

Comment: Look the full answer properly i also used repeated permutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note all the vowels are $A,A,E,E$. Now removing these letters you transform the original word into- $MDSY$. Now, there are-$□M□D□S□Y□$ $=5$ gaps where you can add letters. Now group the letters $A,A,E,E$ together so that they always remain together, and treat them as one letter. So now you can arrange the leters in this group of vowels in $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ ways(repeated permutations). And there were $5$ gaps to fill,also, the letters $M,D,S,Y$ can rearrange between themselves in $4!$ ways, so total number of ways $= \boxed{~~4! \cdot 5\cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!}~~} = \boxed{~~5!\cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!}~~}$

Comment: good point :), R u sure ? Answer given as (5!*4!)/(2!*2!)

Comment: Shrestha i am so sorry i forgot one thing the answer is correct